# Group Chat Circle on Web Chat like a facebook Group Chat UI

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsslC.png)everyone. I am trying to develop a group chat UI of my university project.
But I found it hard to combine the users' profile images in one circle frame.
I want to add 2 or 3 users in a circular frame if there was no group profile.I search on Google and it said me to use canvas. I try this. It doesn't work. How could I combine two or more users into one circular frame ? 
This is my codes.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img1 = loadImage('1.png');
var img2 = loadImage('2.png');

var imagesLoaded = 0;
function main() {
imagesLoaded += 1;

if(imagesLoaded == 2) {
    // composite now
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
}
}

function loadImage(src, onload) {

var img = new Image();

img.onload = onload;
img.src = src;

return img;
}
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve... like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/bxg2Lwa8/

Comment: crystalwill --- Thx a lot. It seems to be ok. I will try. !!

Comment: Canvas can clip multiple images inside a circle. Can you post an example image of the multiple photos in a circle that you're trying to achieve? –

Comment: markE -- I have added image of what I wanted. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain with canvas you have to user globalCompositeOperation:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var img = new Image();
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 308, 308);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 312, 0, 308, 308);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 312, 308, 308);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 312, 312, 308, 308);
}
c.width= 620;
c.height=620;
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(310,310,310,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
img.src = "http://images.movieplayer.it/images/2015/09/28/avatar-1.jpg";
```

```html
<canvas  id ="c" ></canvas>
```

Otherwise you can apply to your canvas a class with border radius:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var img = new Image();
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 308, 308);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 312, 0, 308, 308);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 312, 308, 308);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 312, 312, 308, 308);
}
c.width= 620;
c.height=620;
img.src = "http://images.movieplayer.it/images/2015/09/28/avatar-1.jpg";
```

```css
.rounded {
  border-radius: 310px;
}
```

```html
<canvas  id ="c" class="rounded" ></canvas>
```